# OSMSharp - get informations about actual road

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, openstreetmap

I am trying to code an app for Android (C# - Xamarin), and I loaded a PBF file, I can find route between two places (coordinates). But I dont know how can I get informations about place where I am actualy (by coordinates). I want to know something about road (street) where I am, for example street name, speed limit...

I did not found anything about this. I hope somebody knows how to do that.

Comment: did you find anything on your question

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: I'm the original author of OsmSharp/Itinero.

You can use this code to get info about an edge at a given location:

```
        var routerDb = RouterDb.Deserialize(...); // load routerdb here.
        var router = new Router(routerDb);
        var routerPoint = router.Resolve(Vehicle.Car.Fastest(), new Coordinate(51.269692005119616f, 4.783473014831543f));

        var edge = routerDb.Network.GetEdge(routerPoint.EdgeId);
        var attributes = routerDb.GetProfileAndMeta(edge.Data.Profile, edge.Data.MetaId);

        var speed = Vehicle.Car.Fastest().Speed(attributes);
```

The attributes are a collection of the orginal OSM tags, speed is a speed estimate for the Car profile.